# Element tells how many days left, but it outputs in weeks instead of days. I want it to be in days only

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Currently I have this code (see below). I am pretty sure I need to tweak the array or possibly add a "d" somewhere. Normally I only work on the front end so I'm kind of stepping into uncharted waters here.

The part I think needs tweaking is in the "Format future dates as intervals" section.

```
        if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_test_dates') {
          foreach (element_children($element['#items']) as $key) {
            $item = $element['#items'][$key];
            $close_date = new DateObject($item['value2'], $item['timezone']);
            $start_date = new DateObject($item['value'], $item['timezone']);

            $element = 'time';
            $attributes = array(
              'class' => 'date-display-single',
              'property' => 'dc:date',
              'datatype' => 'xsd:dateTime',
              'datetime' => $close_date->format('m/d/Y H:i'),
            );

            if (REQUEST_TIME < $start_date->format('U')) {
              // Display future start date as "COMING SOON"
              $text = t('COMING SOON');
            }
            else {
              if (REQUEST_TIME >= $close_date->format('U')) {
                // Always display past dates as "CLOSED".
                $text = t('CLOSED');
              }
              else {
           // Format future dates as intervals. 
                $text = t('ENDS IN @days', array(
                  '@days' => strtoupper(date_format_interval($close_date, 1)),
                ));
              }
            }

            $vars['items'][$key]['#markup'] = "<{$element}" .drupal_attributes($attributes) . ">{$text}</{$element}>";
          }
        }
```

Comment: I'm almost certain this is PHP, and if it is, what's `date_format_interval`? I don't remember that function even existed...

Comment: Hi LFlare, thanks for answering. It is PHP, but date_format_interval is a Drupal 7 thing.

Comment: Hahahaha, sorry, can't help with that, I'm strictly vanilla, in code and in hen*ai